# Form submit is not seeing my custom checkboxes as :checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been building a custom form component set on Codepen, but these checkboxes aren't working correctly.

I'm setting both the `prop` to `true` and the `checked` attribute to `"checked"`. You can inspect the elements with the developer tools to check these.

If you click **on** the checkbox, it works. But clicking on the label next to it results in the check not being detected in the form submit even though they are both handled the same as far as I can tell.

**Here's the [Codepen](http://codepen.io/rudi_theunissen/pen/fmgnI?editors=111)**

Any ideas? To me this is one of those *it should be working* situations.

Comment: Do you have a link to the codepen?

Comment: This question would be so much easier to answer with some code.

Comment: It's there now! [Codepen](http://codepen.io/rudi_theunissen/pen/fmgnI?editors=111)

Comment: Before posting here you should try to create an example using the **minimal** amount of code. Often this will result in the issue being resolved before being posted. If it doesn't, and there is too much code to post here, then likely you haven't spent enough time on identifing the issue before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are toggling the checkbox checked property via javascript but the label already toggles that, so you are toggling it twice and you end up with the same value as before.

Try this, remove the "for=..." attribute from your labels and the click on the label will work. That's the ugly solution.

Better solution, change your click callbacks to:

- when you click the fake checkbox: change the fake checkbox status and toggle the value of the real checkbox
- when you click the label: change the fake checkbox status only, don't toggle the value of the checkbox since it has already been toggled

I'm not sure but I think there's an even better solution, but not sure if the checkbox responds to the 'change' event when un/checked. Try it, maybe it works:

- bind the checkbox's "change" event to a function that updates the status of the fake checkbox
- when you click on a fake checkbox just set the property "checked" of the real checkbox to the value you want, the 'change' event should take care of updating your fake checkbox so you don't repeat code (you won't need any javascript on your labels)

Answer (score -1):

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-input-value-dirty-flag

When the user interacts with a form control, it becomes "dirty." That basically means that its value/checkedness disassociates from its `checked`/`value` HTML attribute. Your JavaScript code manipulates the HTML attribute, but not the actual checkedness.